# why does this jQuery function doesn't work? changing color

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to change the color of the icon that i clicked on to red while change the color of the other buttons to none.  But this doesn't work. I know the syntax is wrong but i couldn't get myself around it.

```
$("#appleIcon").click(function(e){
    $("#appleIns").show();
    $("#andIns").hide();
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    $("#andIcon").css("background-color", "none");
});

$("#andIcon").click(function(e){
    $("#appleIns").hide();
    $("#andIns").show();
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    $("#appleIcon").css("background-color", "none");
});
```

Comment: This is extremely out of context. You need to supply some more describing code or text. And you can't call "this" on nothing.

Comment: What are `#appleIns` and `#andIns`.  They are referenced in your JS but we're provided no HTML for proper troubleshooting.

Comment: You will need to also include your HTML and CSS for this question to be answered. Your jQuery syntax seems fine.

Comment: Please try to reproduce the problem here https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

The is no such thing as `background-color:none` in CSS try `.css("background-color","")`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#appleIcon").click(function(){
      $("#appleIns").show();
      $("#andIns").hide();
      $(this).css("background-color", "red");
      $("#andIcon").css("background-color","");
  });

  $("#andIcon").click(function(){
      $("#appleIns").hide();
      $("#andIns").show();
      $(this).css("background-color", "red");
      $("#appleIcon").css("background-color","");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason it was not woking because there is nothing as background-color:none. You can put backgound-color:transparent

Answer (score 0):

**There was error in css property background-color:none there is no such thing like that.
The correct way is :**

```
$("#appleIcon").click(function(e){
    $("#appleIns").show();
    $("#andIns").hide();
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    $("#andIcon").css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,0)");
});

$("#andIcon").click(function(e){
    $("#appleIns").hide();
    $("#andIns").show();
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    $("#appleIcon").css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,0)");
});
```

**or you can try this:**

```
$("#appleIcon").click(function(e){
        $("#appleIns").show();
        $("#andIns").hide();
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
        $("#andIcon").css("background-color", "transparent");
    });

    $("#andIcon").click(function(e){
        $("#appleIns").hide();
        $("#andIns").show();
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
        $("#appleIcon").css("background-color", "transparent");
    });
```

**I suggest you to go with the first method i.e. set "background-color" to "rgba(0,0,0,0)"**